# How to create an interactive based filter (checkboxes) with multiple layers using Carto VL

Tags: javascript, layers, carto, carto-vl

I'm relatively new to coding, and have been developing a map using Carto VL and Mapbox. I've found a way to create a filter within a map where users can turn off and on different categories within that filter. However, I'm trying to create a layer selector that allows for users to turn off and on different layers using checkboxes, or something similar. I've been unable to figure out how to add just one checkbox that responds to an entire layer, as opposed to specific types of data within the layer. How would I be able to create this multi-layered layer selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Airship checkbox](https://carto.com/developers/airship/reference/#/styles/checkbox) component in combination with CARTO VL [`hide`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartolayerhide) and [`show`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartolayershow) layer methods.

You can check how it works [in this working example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/checkbox-filter-carto-vl-airship). In this particular case, I have used Vue as the frontend framework but you can use vanilla js or any other framework. The interesting part is this one:

```
this.layers.forEach(layer => {
  if (layer === 'populated_places') {
    if (value.includes(layer)) this.citiesLayer.show()
    else this.citiesLayer.hide()
  } else {
    if (value.includes(layer)) this.countriesLayer.show()
    else this.countriesLayer.hide()
  }
```

[image: checkbox]